# Does "Find all triplets whose sum is less than some number" have any solution better than O(n3) runtime?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I got asked this on an interview.

> Given an array of ints, find all triplets whose sum is less than some number

After some scrambling I told the interviewer that the best solution would still lead to worst-case runtime O(n<sup>3</sup>) and possibly would need O(n<sup>3</sup>).

The interviewer blatantly disagreed with me and told me "you need to go back to your algorithms...".

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Do you need to output all triplets or just to count them? If you need to output them, it's definitely O(n^3) worst case because there could be O(n^3) such triplets.

Comment: That's a good point, maybe I should have clarified whether I needed to list them or find the number.. I assumed "find" meant get all of them

Comment: It must have meant count them rather than output.  Or else you can set the sum arbitrarily large, and then all triples will be valid, and the output size is O(n^3).

Answer (score 3):

A possible optimization will be:

1. Remove all elements in the array that bigger than `sum`;
2. Sort the array;
3. Run `O(N^2)` to pick up `a[i] + a[j]`, then binary search for `sum - a[i] - a[j]` in the range of `[j + 1, N]`, the index is the number of possible candidates, but you should subtract `j` since they have been covered.

The complexity will be `O(N^2 log N)`, slightly better.

Comment: n^2 log n time, yup, it answers the question.

Comment: Yes, but again the question is asking "Find all" not "Find the number of"...

Comment: output the combinations on the fly, after each binary search, output `a[i]`, `a[j]`, `a[j..index]`

Comment: you're just outputting upper bounds and not all triplets.

Comment: why do you think it's only upper bound? from `j` to `index` covers all possible candidates in that round.

Comment: then you'll have to go through all of them, meaning potentially n. Listing all triplets as mentioned is n choose 3 (finding permutations of 3 in n elements), which will perform O(n^3) no matter what.

Comment: ya that's true, i just proposed a way to output all combinations :)

Comment: We can't remove elements bigger than sum (as suggested in #1), these bigger numbers can sum up with -ve numbers in the array and may make up required triple.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this `O(n^2)` time:

- First, sort the array.
- Then, loop over the array with the first pointer `i`.
- Now, use a second pointer `j` to loop up from there and a third pointer `k` to *simultaneously* loop down from the end.
- Whenever you're in a situation where `A[i]+A[j]+A[k] < X`, you know that the same holds for all `j<k'<k` so increment your count with `k-j` and increment `j`. I keep the hidden invariant that `A[i]+A[j]+A[k+1] >= X`, so incrementing `j` only makes that statement stronger.
- Otherwise, decrement `k`.  When `j` and `k` meet, increment `i`.
- You will only increment `j` and decrement `k`, so they need `O(n)` amortized time to meet.

In pseudocode:

```
count= 0
for i = 0; i < N; i++
    j = i+1
    k = N-1
    while j < k
        if A[i] + A[j] + A[k] < X
            count += k-j
            j++
        else
            k--
```

---

I see that you ask for *all* triplets. It is quite obvious that there can be `O(n^3)` triplets, so if you want them all you will need as much time, worst case.

Comment: How can we do this with your proposed solution? "Given an array S of n integers, find three integers in S such that the sum is closest to a given number, target." I know we should keep track of minimum difference, but I have problem to write 'inside of the while loop' as you suggested.

Comment: @hengameh that's a very different problem. You could post it as such, but I'm pretty sure there are multiple answers to that question here already.

Answer (score 0):

O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

- Sort the list.
- For every element ai, this is how you calculate the number of combinations:

  - Binary search and find maximum aj such that j < i and ai+aj <= total.
  - Binary search and find maximum ak such that k < j and ai+aj+ak <= total

For this particular combination of (ai, aj), k is the number of sums that is less than or equal to total.

Now decrement j and increment k as much as possible (but ai+aj+ak <= total )

The total number of increments and decrements is less than i. So for a particular i the complexity is O(i). Therefore overall complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

I am leaving out many corner conditions, but this should give you an idea.

---

## Edit:

In the worst case there are O(n<sup>3</sup>) solutions. So outputting them explicitly would certainly require O(n<sup>3</sup>) time. There is no way around it.

But if you want to return a implicit list (i.e. a compressed list of combinations) this would still work. An example of compressed output would be (ai, aj, ak) for k in 1:p.

Comment: As above. the question is asking "Find all" not "Find the number of"...

Comment: @Ajk_P In the worst case there are O(n^3) solutions. So outputting them explicitly would certainly require O(n^3) time. But if you want to return a implicit list (i.e. a compressed list of combinations) this would still work. An example of compressed output would be (ai, aj, ak) for k in 1:p.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a problem where the output size matters. For example, if the array contains just `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n` and the maximum value is set at `3n` then every single triplet will be an answer, and you *have to* do Ω(n<sup>3</sup>) work just to list them all. On the other hand, if the maximum value had been `0`, it would be nice to finish in `O(n)` time after confirming all the items are too large.

Basically, we want an [output-sensitive algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm) with a running time that's something like `O(f(n) + t)` where `t` is the output size and `n` is the input size.

An O(n<sup>2</sup> + t) algorithm would work by essentially tracking the transition points where triplets transitioned from being over the limit to under the limit. Then it would yield everything under that surface. The space is three-dimensional so the surface is two-dimensional, and you can track along it from point to point in aggregate constant time.

Here's some python code (untested!):

```py
def findTripletsBelow(items, limit):
  surfaceCoords = []
  s = sorted(items)
  for i in range(len(s)):
    k = len(s)-1
    for j in range(i, len(s))
      while k >= 0 and s[i]+s[j]+s[k] > limit:
        k -= 1
      if k < 0: break
      surfaceCoords.append((i,j,k))

  results = []
  for (i,j,k) in surfaceCoords:
    for k2 in range(k+1):
      results.append((s[i], s[j], s[k2]))
  return results
```